# How do you add a filter with manage form display?

Tags: forms, 9

So I know with form display, you add fields to the content type which then can be re-arranged under form display.

But what about more complicated features, like filtering via taxonomy terms? I know with Manage Display I can use a EVA view and do all kinds of cool stuff.

But with form display, It feels very limited to only the fields added. Is there a way to make form display also work like manage display, where I can pop in a view?

I mostly want to have a form that will filter via taxonomy terms but all I can do is add fields. Not do complex things like views can. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want a taxonomy field in the node form, and be able to filter which terms are selectable to the user up front? Or do you want to present a UI to the user so they can search/filter the terms themselves based on a view/exposed filters that you create?

Comment: You may be looking for the [Entity browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) module.

Comment: Yes, the really cool stuff is in the Media ecosystem which can not only manage Media entities and is entirely based on Views. For basic things there is a Views filtering method already in core. Not in manage form display, but in field settings, you can change the reference method to "Views: filter by an entity reference view" in which you can configure filtering via taxonomy terms.

Comment: @Clive, I believe I actually want both possibilities. Basically what I am going for is I have meals that the user can select, but their just titles. I wanted to add a taxonomy term to them such as breakfast, lunch, dinner, so they are distingisuable in the form mode, but I don't see anyway to filter the form. Only the manage display can you use a view to filter items.

Comment: I would also like to ask, is it possible for exposed filters to display under a entity reference for display type? Because my exposed filters are not showing/displaying at all.