# How to get exposed filters for entity reference to render?

Tags: views, forms, 9

I am using a entity reference view and I am able to filter via taxonomy terms directly, but when I set it to exposed and let the user decide, it does not display on the form. How can I get the expose functionality to actually work?

It works on other things like pages and blocks, but not entity reference.

I have Views Entity Reference Filter and Better Exposed Filters already installed, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: You said it is not shown on the form.  For which users-- admins, authenticated users, anonymous users?

Comment: Its not shown on the form for any users, no matter the role, including admins

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Views filter you can filter via the widget autocomplete if you add a relationship for the taxonomy field, add the taxonomy *Name* field to the field list and then select the *Name* field as search field in Format:Entity Reference list | Settings.

Comment: Not quite what i'm looking for. The user won't know which term to search for so I have it set as checkboxs.

Comment: As [commented already in your previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/310485/how-do-you-add-a-filter-with-manage-form-display#comment394588_310485) this is a very basic thing. If you want to use a full featured View then try an entity browser implementation, like for example https://www.drupal.org/project/content_browser